# Redirected Output

Tags: command-line, bash

I just used a command `ls -l > ~/ls_output` in my `/usr/bin` directory and I'm not sure what happened.  The terminal accepted my command but I don't know what happened to the output or where it went.  I think I may have redirected the output to a new directory called `ls_output` but I'm not sure and I'm also unclear on how `~` works in Bash.

Any advice?

Comment: Considering the nature of your recent questions, I very strongly recommend that you go through a tutorial of the Linux command line interface, such as http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/ or http://www.tldp.org/LDP/gs/node5.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`~` expands to `$HOME`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html), your home directory, such as `/home/justin` or `/home/muru`.

So `ls -l > ~/ls_output` will create a file in your home directory, redirecting the output to the file at `~/ls_output` (not a directory), creating a new file if necessary and raising an error if it can't.

Do `ls -l ~/ls_output` to verify that the file was created.

Do `cat ~/ls_output` to see the contents.

Comment: Once again muru, I really appreciate the help!  I just tried "cat ~/ls_output" and was able to view the contents.  However when I try to see this file in a list (just to verify) using my "ls" command in the current directory, I can't seem to find it.  I created this file in my "/usr/bin" directory, so shouldn't it be in the "ls" list somewhere?

Comment: @Justin you ran the command in `/usr/bin`, but as I say in the second sentence, the file is created in your home directory (the `~/ls_output` expands to `/home/justin/ls_output` and the full path is used). You will see it in the `ls` output if you do `ls ~`.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm following you.  Does the "~" and "/" cause it to be created there?

Comment: @Justin yes, because that specifies the path of the target file. Without a path and just a file name, the current directory will be used.